# XML from response disappears on refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

Got a strange one here, which certainly has me scratching my head.

**Program:**
Uploads a spreadsheet via iFrame/AJAX to the server.
.JSP/APACHE POI reads, validates, and returns the data in XML format.
JavaScript reads the XML and displays it in a table for visual confirmation.

**Problem:**
The program works perfectly - until the user refreshes the page. The XML does not return properly, maintaining the formatting but missing the data. Uploading a different file or refreshing again does not change anything, the XML response remains the same.

**XML:**

```
<records>
    <groups>
        <group>
            <name>
                <cell>B9</cell>
                <value>Group Name</value>
                <error></error>
            </name>

            <...more data...>

        </group>
    </groups>

    <data>
        <groups>3</groups>
        <users>0</users>
        <errors>5</errors>
    </data>
</records>
```

Is how it should appear, but instead upon refreshing the return is:

```
<records>
    <groups />

    <data>
        <groups>3</groups>
        <users>0</users>
        <errors>5</errors>
    </data>
</records>
```

The bottom three numbers (groups, users, and errors) are .jsp variables which are incremented during the validation process, which means that there has to be data for them to have a value. Each time the page is run the variables are set to defaults of 0, blank, etc.

As far as I can see, there are only two possibilities:

- The AJAX is returning a cached page
- The .JSP is remembering the previous request

But I have explored no-cache headers, file re-names, etc, to no avail.

**Other notes:**
The iFrame/AJAX successfully uploads the file to the server every time
The correct file name is passed to the validation .jsp page
The first run always works perfectly

The validation code is quite long, but I can find somewhere to post it if really needed (but as the code runs perfectly the first time, I think it must be a communication/cache related issue). If anyone has any thoughts, I'm listening.

Comment: I guess you're experiencing the problem that Ajax request doesn't get cached. I'm not really sure if you can enable it, but you can try the advices given in [this blog entry](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/08/07/ajax-caching-two-important-facts/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slept on it, and I seem to have solved it this morning.

For whatever reason, each time the .JSP file is called it is using the exact same process as before, rather than reloading and redoing the page from scratch each time. I don't know why, but I guess it may be a setting on the server I am not aware of.

I reiterated the variable reset within the main procedure to default and it is now working properly.